# Auto search in searchDisplayController

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

Normally, user enter text in uisearch bar and when user tap on search button, we request web service and show in searchResultsTableView.

My current case is instead of typing in uisearch bar, it is to put search text programmatically there and search. So, I do like this. Problem is that uisearchdisplaycontrollerdimming view is not hidden back. It block user interaction and cannot see content. May I know how to do?

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];

//Put text to search bar, retrieve data and show in searchResultsTableView
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these blog: [building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview](http://jduff.github.io/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/)

**SearchViewController.h**

```
//
//  SearchViewController.h
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController
 <UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *tableData;

    UIView *disableViewOverlay;

    UITableView *theTableView;
    UISearchBar *theSearchBar;
}

@property(retain) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@property(retain) UIView *disableViewOverlay;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *theTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *theSearchBar;

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar activate:(BOOL) active;

@end
```

**SearchViewController.m**

```
//
//  SearchViewController.m
//
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@implementation SearchViewController
@synthesize tableData;
@synthesize disableViewOverlay;
@synthesize theSearchBar;
@synthesize theTableView;


// Initialize tableData and disabledViewOverlay 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.disableViewOverlay = [[UIView alloc]
     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,44.0f,320.0f,416.0f)];
    self.disableViewOverlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;
}

// Since this view is only for searching give the UISearchBar 
// focus right away
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.theSearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate Methods

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
  // We don't want to do anything until the user clicks 
  // the 'Search' button.
  // If you wanted to display results as the user types 
  // you would do that here.
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // searchBarTextDidBeginEditing is called whenever 
    // focus is given to the UISearchBar
    // call our activate method so that we can do some 
    // additional things when the UISearchBar shows.
    [self searchBar:searchBar activate:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // searchBarTextDidEndEditing is fired whenever the 
    // UISearchBar loses focus
    // We don't need to do anything here.
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // Clear the search text
    // Deactivate the UISearchBar
    searchBar.text=@"";
    [self searchBar:searchBar activate:NO];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // Do the search and show the results in tableview
    // Deactivate the UISearchBar

    // You'll probably want to do this on another thread
    // SomeService is just a dummy class representing some 
    // api that you are using to do the search
    NSArray *results = [SomeService doSearch:searchBar.text];

    [self searchBar:searchBar activate:NO];

    [self.tableData removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableData addObjectsFromArray:results];
    [self.theTableView reloadData];
}

// We call this when we want to activate/deactivate the UISearchBar
// Depending on active (YES/NO) we disable/enable selection and 
// scrolling on the UITableView
// Show/Hide the UISearchBar Cancel button
// Fade the screen In/Out with the disableViewOverlay and 
// simple Animations
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar activate:(BOOL) active{  
    self.theTableView.allowsSelection = !active;
    self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = !active;
    if (!active) {
        [disableViewOverlay removeFromSuperview];
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    } else {
        self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;
        [self.view addSubview:self.disableViewOverlay];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeIn" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0.6;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        // probably not needed if you have a details view since you 
        // will go there on selection
        NSIndexPath *selected = [self.theTableView 
            indexPathForSelectedRow];
        if (selected) {
            [self.theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selected 
                animated:NO];
        }
    }
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:active animated:YES];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"SearchResult";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
         reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    id *data = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = data.name;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management Methods

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];    
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [theTableView release], theTableView = nil;
    [theSearchBar release], theSearchBar = nil;
    [tableData dealloc];
    [disableViewOverlay dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```